# html controls not being shown/hidden when toggled

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to enable some html controls from being shown depending on when a time condition is true.

My controls are as follows:

```
<span id="t"><button id="ctr">Centre Map</button></span><span id="t2"><form name="Follow"><input type="checkbox" id ="FT" name="FT" onclick = "TitanicCheckBox( this )"><span id="FTText">Follow</span></form></span>
```

And my toggle control is as follows:

```
function HideControls( tof )
{
  if (tof==true)  // hide and remove area where controls would be
  {

    document.getElementById("t").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("FT").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("FTText").style.display = "none";
  }
  else
  {

    document.getElementById("t").style.display = "all";
    document.getElementById("FT").style.display = "all";
    document.getElementById("FTText").style.display = "all";
  }
}
```

The function is being called and the correct "if" condition is entered (    HideControls( false );), but the controls aren't being toggled. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The `else` should use `.style.display = "";`, not `="all"`.

Comment: try `display = "visible";`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

In display property, value `all` doesn't exist. You should use `block` or `initial`.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers that will allow you to immensely shorten your `HideControls` method:

- Cache your DOM elements in variables outside your function. This means you don't have to use `getElementById` every time the function is called.
- Use `.style.display = 'none'` and `.style.display = ''` to hide and show the controls, respectively.
- Use the ternary operator instead of an if-else statement; in this case it is much terser to set every variable to `(tof ? 'none' : '')`.

```js
var $t = document.getElementById('t')
var $FT = document.getElementById("FT")
var $FTText = document.getElementById("FTText")

function HideControls (tof) {
  $t.style.display = $FT.style.display = $FTText.style.display = (tof ? 'none' : '')
}
```

```html
<button onclick="HideControls(false)">Show Controls</button>
<button onclick="HideControls(true)">Hide Controls</button>
<hr>


<span id="t"><button id="ctr">Centre Map</button></span><span id="t2"><form name="Follow"><input type="checkbox" id ="FT" name="FT" onclick = "TitanicCheckBox( this )"><span id="FTText">Follow</span></form>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question wasn't really clear, is this what you're trying to achieve?

```js
function HideControls( tof )
{
  if (tof.checked==true)  // hide and remove area where controls would be
  {

    document.getElementById("t").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("FT").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("FTText").style.display = "none";
  }
  else
  {

    document.getElementById("t").style.display = "all";
    document.getElementById("FT").style.display = "all";
    document.getElementById("FTText").style.display = "all";
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="t"><button id="ctr">Centre Map</button></span><span id="t2"><form name="Follow"><input type="checkbox" id ="FT" name="FT" onclick = "HideControls( this )"><span id="FTText">Follow</span></form></span>
```